# How should I fix this mistake in my code in Python?

Tags: python

I'm making a movie theatre booking system using python and csv as part of a school project. I've created a csv file that stores the status of all the seats, i.e. 0=available and 1=booked. I've imported this file into python and wrote out code to allow the user to select the seat they wish to book and IF that seat is not booked (status=0) then the person will be able to book it and the csv file will be updated to reflect the same (status=1). For some reason, I'm able to book seats that've already been booked even though I wrote code preventing me from doing this. Can please someone tell me the mistake I've made? I'll attach the relavent pieces of code below:

```py
import csv

with open('seats.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    seats = list(csv.reader(csvfile))


def bookSeat():
    for row in seats:
        print(row)
    print("Booking a Seat by Row/Column")
    booked = False
    while booked == False:
        row = int(input("Enter a row number (between 0 and 5) "))
        column = int(input("Enter a column number (between 0 and 7) "))

        if seats[row][column] == 1:
            print("This seat is already booked.")

        else:
            print("This seat is empty.")
            print("Booking seat...")
            seats[row][column] = 1
            print("We have now booked this seat for you.")
            booked = True

            # Rewrite the CSV with the new list of seats
            writer = csv.writer(open('seats.csv', 'w', newline = ''))
            writer.writerows(seats)
```

As seen in the code, if the status of the seat in the database is 1, the message "This seat is already booked" should be shown but for some reason, it continues on with the booking.
Here's the place where bookSeat function is used later on:

```py
if choice == "Customer":
    print("+============================+")
    print("+   CINEMA BOOKING SYSTEM    +")
    print("+============================+")
    print("")
    print("1 - Book a Seat")
    print("x - Exit")
 
    choice = input("What would you like to do? ")

    if choice=="1":
        bookSeat()
        displayBookings()
        whatNext()

    elif choice=="x":    
        print("Good Bye!")
        
    else:
        print("Invalid Menu Option")
        print("Good Bye!")
```

Comment: Hint: check your indentation.

Comment: `if seats[row][column]==1` is probably the problem; you read this data straight from a file so it's likely the value there is a string `"1"` instead of an int.

Comment: Also, how often do theaters have row/seat 0? I'd hazard a guess that now very often. You should probably change your input question and then just subtract 1 from whatever row/seat a customer has selected.

Comment: @shreenath can you please check that the indentation in your code is exactly the same one as the question after I edited it? Most of the times the indentation errors come from copy pasting the code in SO, I recommend using triple backwards quote to open and close code blocks and that way you can copy paste your code without further changes. If you also add python word after the opening triple backwards quote you will force to use the coloring for python and not let SO decide which language you are writting.

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks for the help. For some reason that didn't click in my mind. It works now :)

Comment: @pavel Thanks for the suggestion. I'll implement it rn.

Comment: @shreenath do not forget to also write strings to the file: `seats[row][column] = "1"` or you will have the same issue if the seat was booked in the same execution as in memory you will have it stored as an integer, despite the file storing it as a string automatically.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of menu-based programs, I wrote a menu function that handled most of the menu logic and then reused it in multiple of my programs. Something similar to the following:

```py
def menu(header, options, request):
    """
    Creates a function that will print the menu and return a valid option

    :param header: text to show at the top of the menu
    :param options: list of options to be printed
    :param request: text to show when requesting an option
    :return: function that will print the menu and return a valid option
    """
    # First, lets add the numbers to each option and prepare it to be printed
    # so that we only do this once
    digits = 0  # Maximum digits length to print them vertically aligned
    length = len(options)
    while length > 0:
        digits += 1
        length //= 10
    options_text = "\n".join([
        f"\t{i+1:{digits}d}) {option}" for i, option in enumerate(options)
    ])
    options_text += f"\n\t{0:{digits}d}) Exit"

    def print_menu():
        while True:
            print(header)
            print(options_text)

            try:
                choice = int(input(request + " "))
            except ValueError:
                print("Unable to parse input as integer.\n")
            else:
                # If the option is valid return it
                if 0 <= choice <= len(options):
                    return choice
                print("Invalid option.\n")

    return print_menu
```

and then you would use it like this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_menu = menu(
        "\n".join([
            "+============================+",
            "+   CINEMA BOOKING SYSTEM    +",
            "+============================+",
        ]),
        [
            "Book a seat",
        ],
        "What would you like to do?",
    )
    while (choice := print_menu()) != 0:
        if choice == 1:
            pass  # Option 1
        elif choice == 2:
            pass  # Option 2
    print("Good bye!")
```

And it will generate menus like this, with Exit as the zero option written last:

```
+============================+
+   CINEMA BOOKING SYSTEM    +
+============================+
    1) Book a seat
    0) Exit
What would you like to do?
```

**Note:** the usage requires Python 3.8+, previously you could use it like this with exactly the same result:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_menu = menu(
        "\n".join([
            "+============================+",
            "+   CINEMA BOOKING SYSTEM    +",
            "+============================+",
        ]),
        [
            "Book a seat",
        ],
        "What would you like to do?",
    )
    choice = None
    while choice != 0:
        choice = print_menu()
        if choice == 1:
            pass  # Option 1
        elif choice == 2:
            pass  # Option 2
    print("Good bye!")
```

By applying this function to your code, and doing some additional improvements (using strings instead of integers to fix your issue, enumerating the rows and columns starting from 1, extracting read and save to functions, ...):

```py
import csv


def menu(header, options, request):
    pass  # Copy the code from above


def read_bookings(path):
    with open(path, 'r', newline='') as csv_file:
        return list(csv.reader(csv_file))


def save_bookings(path, bookings):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerows(bookings)


def display_bookings(bookings):
    for row in bookings:
        print(row)


def book_seat(bookings):
    print("Booking a Seat by Row/Column")
    while True:
        row = int(input("Enter a row number (between 1 and 6) ")) - 1
        column = int(input("Enter a column number (between 1 and 8) ")) - 1

        if bookings[row][column] == '1':
            print("This seat is already booked.")

        else:
            print("This seat is empty.")
            print("Booking seat...")

            bookings[row][column] = '1'
            # Rewrite the CSV with the new list of seats
            save_bookings('seats.csv', bookings)

            print("We have now booked this seat for you.")

            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_menu = menu(
        "\n".join([
            "+============================+",
            "+   CINEMA BOOKING SYSTEM    +",
            "+============================+",
        ]),
        [
            "Book a seat",
        ],
        "What would you like to do?",
    )
    while (choice := print_menu()) != 0:
        if choice == 1:  # Book a seat
            seats = read_bookings('seats.csv')
            display_bookings(seats)
            book_seat(seats)
            display_bookings(seats)

        elif choice == 2:  # Still not implemented
            pass

    print("Good bye!")
```